# how can I check in vbscript in componetone report if an image file exist?

Tags: vbscript, componentone

I have a database with 2 alternive picture filenames pic1 and pic2. If the first picture file does not exist i want to print the second.

in the onFormat Event of the report I want to do somthing like:

if FileExists(pic1) 
Then 
   article.Picture=pic1
Else
   article.Picture=Pic2
EndIf

But I do not succeed as the componentone vbscript is not so well documented

Comment: Are you using C1Report or FlexReport? Is this for a designer? There is nothing called C1 VBScript, only VBScript with fields rendered from C1Report/FlexReport.

Comment: I am using c1Reports Build 2/4.6.20112.54408 and have the code article.Picture= pic1 in the OnFormat Event (in script editor window) which works! pic1 is the fullpath to a pic that is coming from a database field. But now I want to check if the file exists and if not i want to use a pic named pic2 coming from anothe db field.

Comment: Refer the answer.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

C1Report VBScrit engine does not support CreateObject, and thus this is not supported from report designer.

---

<del>There are no inbuilt IO commands in VBScript. Instead, you can use FileSystemObject to check this. Use this function to determine if a file exists:</del>

```
Function FileExists(filePath)
      Dim fso, exists
      Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
      If (fso.FileExists(filePath)) Then
        exists = True
      Else
        exists = False
      End If
      FileExists = exists
    End Function
```

<del>Use this function in your VBScript editor</del>

Comment: I tried this already, but Functions seem to be not supported by c1reports.If put this code in onFormat:Function FileExists(filePath)
  Dim fso, exists
  Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
  If (fso.FileExists(filePath)) Then
    exists = True
  Else
    exists = False
  End If
  FileExists = exists
End Function

IF FileExists(bilddatei)=True THEN ArtBild.Picture=bilddatei ELSE ArtBild.picture=bildalternativ END IF

Comment: Why not add this function as a global script? `VBScript Editor> Script:Report.GlobalScripts`

Comment: I do not know where I can do that.

Comment: seems it does not exist in my old version.

Comment: The question is if CreateObject is supported by C1Report's VBScript engine. Let me investigate on this, I would update the post once done

Comment: the only workarround in Visual studio is to load the report data to a datatable and do the logic there and then pass the dt as report datasource.